# Invert Tokenizer Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to make an autoencoder of text under Keras.
I use the Tokenizer from the preprocess module.

After I trained the encoder and the decoder I was wondering how to revert the list of integer into a list of words.
I searched in the official doc but there is nothing to invert the Tokenizer process.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks to you!

Comment: There is a `word_index` attribute which is a dictionary that maps words to indices. You try inverting that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text        import Tokenizer
```

Assuming your corpus is inside the `corpus` variable:

```
tok_obj = Tokenizer(num_words=10, oov_token='<OOV>')
tok_obj.fit_on_texts(corpus)
```

Assuming your sequences are contained into `processed_seq`. Here an example:

```
processed_seq = tok_obj.texts_to_sequences(['senteces you want to predict on here'])
```

Build the dictionary `inv_map` and use It! list comprehension can be used below to compress the code.

```
inv_map = {v: k for k, v in tok_obj.word_index.items()}

for seq in processed_seq:
    for tok in seq:
        print(inv_map[tok])
```

If you need a complete example you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69643477/5404074) answer.