# ValueError: Input has n_features=12 while the model has been trained with n_features=2494

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have trained a model using count_vectorizer, Tfidf_transformer and sgd classifier.

This is the tokenizer part

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
# The maximum number of words to be used. (most frequent)
MAX_NB_WORDS = 50000
# Max number of words in each complaint.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
# This is fixed.
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(master_df['Observation'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
```

I trained the model

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
cv=CountVectorizer(max_df=1.0,min_df=1, stop_words=stop_words, max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1,3))
X=cv.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42, stratify=y)
sgd = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, max_iter=5, tol=None)),
               ])
sgd.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = sgd.predict(X_test)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred,target_names=my_tags))
```

This part works fine
When I try to use this model to predict using this code

```
sentence="Drill was not in operation in the mine at the time of visit."
test=preprocess_text(sentence)
test=test.lower()
print(test)
test=[test] 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
#print(word_index)
test1=cv.transform(test)
print(test1)
output=sgd.predict(test1)
output
```

It gives me this error.

```
ValueError: Input has n_features=12 while the model has been trained with n_features=2494
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18044/596445027.py in <module>
      9 test1=cv.fit_transform(test)
     10 print(test1)
---> 11 output=sgd.predict(test1)
     12 output

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    118 
    119         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 120         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    121         # update the docstring of the returned function
    122         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    416         Xt = X
    417         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 418             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    419         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    420 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in transform(self, X, copy)
   1491             expected_n_features = self._idf_diag.shape[0]
   1492             if n_features != expected_n_features:
-> 1493                 raise ValueError("Input has n_features=%d while the model"
   1494                                  " has been trained with n_features=%d" % (
   1495                                      n_features, expected_n_features))

ValueError: Input has n_features=12 while the model has been trained with n_features=2494
```

I think the problem lies in `word_index=tokenizer` line but I dont know how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We **never** `fit_transform` the *test* set; we use simply `transform` instead. Change to

```
test1=cv.transform(test)
```

Similarly, you should not re-fit the tokenizer on the *test* data with `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test)`; you should change this to

```
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test)
```

See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) and the SO thread [What does Keras Tokenizer method exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956000/what-does-keras-tokenizer-method-exactly-do) for more on `Tokenizer`.